# Woocommerce Bookings subtract "resource" from a reservation

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

good, see if you can help me.

I want to subtract the resources from a Woocommerce Bookings reservation.
I have a resource in Woocommerce Bookings called "Bus" with Available Quantity 17.

And I would like for each reservation to subtract that resource.
For example, 17 subtract 5 so there is 12 left to reserve that product.

Do you know someone how you could do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is already built into the woocommerce bookings plugin. If a customer tries to purchase more than is available it will show an error saying something like önly 12 places available on that date".